# UIButton won't stay highlighted on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a method defined:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button {
    button.highlighted = YES;
    button.selected = YES;
}
```

The problem is, the button doesn't stay persistently highlighted. I don't want the highlight to go away after the button is let go off by a user's gesture. It needs to stay persistent. The method is definitely being invoked as per NSLog and break points.

Why can't I leave my button highlighted/selected?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the same button, why not use IBAction to link the behaviour to the IB?

Answer (score -3):

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    button.highlighted = YES;
    button.selected = YES;
}
```

Change your code to the above. You are passing a UIButton when you want to be passing a touch response.